# proftpd: unknown configuration directive 'ServerIdent'

Tags: centos, centos7, proftpd

**Hello,**

I setup proftpd on server, but when i want to start it fails with error message:

*fatal: unknown configuration directive 'ServerIdent' on line 78 of '/etc/proftpd.conf'*

It is the default configuration file, i changed nothing. It was a new installation.
When i comment the line, it fails with different directives.

**CentOS Version:** 7.4.1708

**ProFTPD Version:** 1.3.5e

I searched for error, but all says configuration file may be incorret. But the configuration file is the default file, nothing changed.
What can cause the error?

Results of: *proftpd -td10*

```
proftpd -td10
Checking syntax of configuration file
proftpd[14561]: using PCRE 8.32 2012-11-30
proftpd[14561]: using TCP receive buffer size of 87380 bytes
proftpd[14561]: using TCP send buffer size of 16384 bytes
proftpd[14561]: testing Unix domain socket using S_ISFIFO
proftpd[14561]: testing Unix domain socket using S_ISSOCK
proftpd[14561]: using S_ISSOCK macro for Unix domain socket detection
proftpd[14561]: mod_tls/2.6: using OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
proftpd[14561]: mod_memcache/0.1: using libmemcached-1.0.16
proftpd[14561]: using 'UTF-8' as local charset for UTF-8 conversion
proftpd[14561]: fatal: unknown configuration directive 'ServerIdent' on line 78 of '/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

The errored line in /etc/proftpd.conf file:

```
77. ServerName                      "ProFTPD server"
78. ServerIdent                     on "FTP Server ready."
79. ServerAdmin                     root@localhost
80. DefaultServer                   on
```

Comment: The problem was occuring while system locale is: tr_TR.utf8 Switching locale to en_US.utf8 fixed the problem. I don't know why ProFTPD does not start while locale is Turkish. Maybe some other locales have problem too. Maybe ProFTPD or its dependencies does not support all locales.